# How to Put <a></a> tags around <img> tags

Tags: html, html-table

I'm creating a table with nine images and nine links, the links can be different from the images. I managed to do the pictures using the image tag but don't know who to wrap the `<a> </a>` tags around the image tags.

This is what I have tried:

```
<td><a href="www.*link*.com"</a><img src="http://www.*link*.jpg" /></td>
```

and;

```
<td><a href="www.link.com><img src="http://www.link.jpg" /><a/></td>
```

Comment: The first is totally wrong. The second has two little mistakes:
<td><a href="www.link.com"><img src="http://www.link.com/image.jpg" /><a/></td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the last quote marks on the second one otherwise it is correct

Current

```
 <td><a href="www.link.com><img src="http://www.link.jpg" /><a/></td>
```

Should be

```
 <td><a href="www.link.com"><img src="http://www.link.jpg" /><a/></td>
```